# Select all elements from dictionary when the key is contained in the second dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:
`Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> d1;` and `Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> d2;`

I want two execute a linq query to select from d1 all elements where `d2..ContainsKey(d1.key);`

Comment: Great! How about writing your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var results = d1.Where(x => d2.ContainsKey(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Or create another dictionary from selected data:

```
var results = d1.Where(x => d2.ContainsKey(x.Key)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the decimal-values as result:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> result = d2.Keys.Intersect(d1.Keys).Select(k => d1[k]);
```

If you want a new dictionary from the intersection:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, decimal> result = d2.Keys.Intersect(d1.Keys)
                                              .ToDictionary(k => k, k => d1[k]);
```

Comment: Was waiting for someone to write this one.

Comment: I want both keys and values not only values in a dictionary that's my problem

Comment: isn't that what you get if you remove the Select(k => kd1[k]); ?

Comment: @gsmida: I've assumed that you want only the value, edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
from rec in d1 where d2.ContainsKey(rec.key) select d1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var values = d1.Where(kvp => d2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)).Select(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: I want to retrieve a dictionary not only values

Answer (score 1):

```
d1.Keys.Intersect(d2.Keys).ToDictionary( x => x, x => d1[x]);
```

or

```
d1.Keys.Where(k => d2.ContainsKey(k)).ToDictionary( x => x, x => d1[x]);
```